# QR code using the bootstrap 'card' background colour issues

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm using the bootstrap class="card" and I'm trying to use a customised background colour to fill the card but the class="card-text" section will not be filled with the background colour although the class="card" wraps the class="card-text"

```
    <div class="content">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="images/qr-code.png" class="card-img" alt="qr-code">
    <div class="card-text">
      <h3>Improve your front-end skills by building new projects</h3>
      <p>Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    </div>
  </div>











 .card {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 300px;
    height: 490px;
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    border-radius: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    }
    
    .content{
      width: 350px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      margin: 3rem auto 2rem;
      padding: 1rem 1rem 1.5rem;
      background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
      border-radius: 20px;
    }
```

Comment: Use your browser dev tools inspect facility to see exactly what/where is setting the background color.

Comment: hi. Thank you, i did have a look and it shows me that the color in the <div class="card-text"> is being inherited by the body. But its wrapped in the card.. so why isn't it taken the background colour of the card set in the css..??

Answer (score 0):

Try this and change your color

```css
 .card {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 300px;
        height: 490px;
        background-color: red; /* change the color whatever your want*/
        border-radius: 15px;
        text-align: center;
        }
        
        .content{
          width: 350px;
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
          margin: 3rem auto 2rem;
          padding: 1rem 1rem 1.5rem;
          background-color: green; /* change the color whatever you want */
          border-radius: 20px;
        }
```

```html
<html>

<body>
<div class="content">
  <div class="card">
   <!-- replace your image here -->
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/180" class="card-img" alt="qr-code">
      <div class="card-text">
        <h3>Improve your front-end skills by building new projects</h3>
          <p>Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This just changes the colour but doesn't solve the problem which is that my  <div class="card-text"> isn't being filled with the background colour which is wrapped in the <div class="card">

Comment: Do you want change the text color with card background ? did your check with inspect tool?